# About Mac histories of programs?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, bash, history

My friend asked me a question about "Is it possible to check what programs you open and you made" and I didn't know if its possible or not so I want to ask you if its possible or not.

Like how can you find out what you did on a Mac and delete the history or edit something on it.

Comment: Check Parental Controls https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25799?locale=en_US (if that is what you mean, your question is not very clear).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing is the "Recent Items" lists in the Apple menu.

There is more detailed information in `/var/log/system.log` but it's not easy to parse.

Comment: How to delete or edit the logs and how to open it via terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a managed machine (like at a business) it is possible for the administrator to have your machine send information to another computer that allows them to see not only what applications have been launched for a given time period, but also how long they were open. Reports can also be generated to show what versions of software are installed and when, how and for how long users were logged into a machine. The basic interface for this management tool is "Remote Desktop." As the information is stored on a different computer, I'm not sure there is a reliable way for a user to delete it.

Relevant page on Apple's website --
http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/assetmanagement.html